# Multiple ellipsis when defining syntax

Tags: racket

I need to define a syntax for a `fancy-sublist` procedure that works like this

```
> (fancy-sublist 1 2 -> 3 4 5 <- 6 7)
(3 4 5)
```

I tried to implement it by defining a new syntax

```
(define-syntax fancy-sublist
  (syntax-rules (-> <-)
    ((_ x xs ... -> dis dis1 ... <- y ys ...) 
      (keep only the elements in the middle))))
```

But it seems I cannot put an ellipsis after another.

Is it possible to use define-syntax to do what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [the `syntax/parse` library](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse.html) instead of `syntax-rules`; it’s more capable in every way, and it produces considerably better error messages even when both can technically get the job done. I consider `syntax-rules` a legacy feature from Scheme; `syntax-parse` should really be the default choice in modern Racket. It copes with your example perfectly fine:

```
#lang racket

(require syntax/parse/define)

(define-syntax (<- stx)
  (raise-syntax-error #f "cannot be used as an expression" stx))

(define-syntax-parser fancy-sublist
  #:literals [<- ->]
  [(_ x xs ... -> dis dis1 ... <- y ys ...)
   #'(list dis dis1 ...)])
```

```
> (fancy-sublist 1 2 -> 3 4 5 <- 6 7)
'(3 4 5)
```

Comment: Furthermore, syntax/parse lets you use `...+` to express one-or-more -- simplifying the pattern to `(_ xs ...+ -> dis ...+ <- ys ...+)` and the template to `#'(list dis ...)`.

Comment: OMG alexis. How did you get hyperlinks to work. I <3 <3 <3 them. ^.^

Comment: @LeifAndersen markdown can include HTML, so you can stick `<a>` elements inside the `<pre><code> ...`?

Comment: Sure. Although looking at the markdown for Alexis's response it looks like it was generated. I am primarily curious how she did it (if it was generated).

Comment: @LeifAndersen I didn’t generate it, I did it by hand, but I was considering maybe trying to write something to do it automatically in the future.

Comment: First of all, thanks Alexis for the great answer.
You said that define-syntax can still be used to solve my problem, could you show me how you would do it?

Comment: @FilippoCremonese `define-syntax-parser` is just a tiny macro that expands into `define-syntax` combined with `syntax-parser`, as the documentation explains.

Comment: tks, saved my day, almost used the (begin

Comment: Thanks for this.  I landed here with a very similar problem in Guile not Racket - In case it helps anyone I found I could employ the same use of multiple ellipses in Guile by using a port of syntax/parse -  https://gitlab.com/guile-syntax-parse/guile-syntax-parse - This  continues to work in Guile 3.0.7 despite its age.  You could of course then look at the code generated by the macro if you want a pure Guile solution, but it's hard to argue with the comment from @AlexisKing that this is more capable and clearer too.

Answer (score 0):

Although you took an alternative approach, here is the answer to your original question.

The problem can be solved with `syntax-rules` by splitting it into two parts:

- `fancy-head`
- `fancy-tail`

Both can be solved by recursion.

I am starting with the tail part, because it is a bit easier.  Recursive macros need at least two rules: one for the termination and one for the recursion.  First comes the termination and after that the recursion rule.  If you do the recursion first, the macro will never stop.  The condition for the termination is the occurrence of the token `->` in front of the tail. When we see that, we return the tail. Otherwise we throw away the first element and recurse with the rest.

```lisp
(define-syntax fancy-tail
  (syntax-rules (->)
    ;; termination
    ((_ -> tail ...)
     (list tail ...))
    ;; recursion
    ((_ x tail ...)
     (fancy-tail tail ...))
    ))

(fancy-tail 1 2 -> 3 4 5) ;; => (3 4 5)
```

The head part is a bit more complicated, because we have to accumulate the elements of the head, while we are searching for the token `<-`.  In order to accumulate we need an accumulator, which is an additional argument.  Again we search by recursion, again we need two rules and again we start with the termination.  The termination condition is, when we see the last element of the middle followed by the token `<-` and followed by anything else.  In that case we return the items of the accumulated head together with the item found last.  In the recursive step we append the first item of the already accumulated items of the head and continue with the rest.

```lisp
(define-syntax fancy-head
  (syntax-rules (<-)
    ;; termination
    ((_ (head ...) item <- x ...)
     (list head ... item))
    ;; recursion
    ((_ (head ...) item x ...)
     (fancy-head (head ... item) x ...))
    ))

(fancy-head () 3 4 5 <- 6 7) ;; => (3 4 5)
```

Now you just have to put both together.  Again the order is important.  More specific rules have to be put at the beginning.  Less specific rules go to the end.  The rules for the head are more specific, because of the additional accumulator.  So the head rules are at the beginning and the tail rules are at the end.

```lisp
(define-syntax fancy-sublist
  (syntax-rules (-> <-)
    ;; fancy-head
    ((_ (head ...) item <- x ...)
     (list head ... item))
    ((_ (head ...) item x ...)
     (fancy-sublist (head ... item) x ...))
    ;; fancy-tail
    ((_ -> tail ...)
     (fancy-sublist () tail ...))
    ((_ x tail ...)
     (fancy-sublist tail ...))
    ))

(fancy-sublist 1 2 -> 3 4 5 <- 6 7) ;; => (3 4 5)
```

Works in [Chez](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/), [Chibi](https://github.com/ashinn/chibi-scheme/) and [Gambit](https://gambitscheme.org/) out of the box.